# Soundcloud content retrieval without a client ID. Is it at all possible?

Tags: soundcloud

Soundcloud have locked off their API and nobody is able to request a new Client ID. Before they closed it off they were simply ignoring API key requests for months. They obviously have their reasons but it's been this way for ages now and it's really annoying.

Does anybody know any cheeky workarounds to retrieve track data from a supplied username?

I've tried parsing the dom and scraping it but it doesn't work as they return "no javascript" errors when scraping which renders the homepage and not the user page.

Example :

```
$url = "https://soundcloud.com/username/tracks";
$dom = new Dom;
$dom->loadFromUrl($url);

$dom = $dom->find('title',0)->text;
```

**Should** return :

```
username | Free Listening on SoundCloud
```

But instead we get :

```
SoundCloud - Hear the world’s sounds
```

Comment: I think this is not possible, you need an auth in order to make a rest

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be to use an existing public API key, for example, [the CLIENT_ID youtube-dl uses to download SoundCloud tracks](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/youtube_dl/extractor/soundcloud.py).

You'll first need to get the id from the username.  We'll use the `/resolve` endpoint for this:

```
HTTP GET: http://api.soundcloud.com/resolve?url=http://soundcloud.com/{username}&client_id={CLIENT_ID}
```

Then, get the user's tracks from the `/users/{id}/tracks` endpoint:

```
HTTP GET: https://api.soundcloud.com//users/{id}/tracks
```

Comment: JAL, did you mean to take the hardcoded CLIENT_ID out of that script? The one on this line? https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/master/youtube_dl/extractor/soundcloud.py#L312 . I imagine we need to come up with a new `CLIENT_ID` everytime we call. I have no idea how to do this though. I'm assuming the info is available somewhere since you don't need to be logged into to make these requests.