# soundcloud api how get clientId

Tags: api, soundcloud

On page https://developers.soundcloud.com/ 
Register a new app (Currently unavailable)
A question for developers. How soon will fix the registration of apps?
Is it possible to register my application in manual mode?
I need my clientId!

Comment: Did you have a chance to look at API documentation?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what kind of content you want to access. 
If you need only public content than you can obtain the `CLIENT ID` from your AJAX requests made to `soundcloud`. Open network debugger in your browser and explore AJAX requests you should see some queries made to `api....` and the query string should contain `client id`:

```
https://api-v2.soundcloud.com/tracks/687584815/playlists_without_albums?offset=85&limit=5&client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently they haven't given out new client IDs for months ([another user says so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49634738/soundcloud-content-retrieval-without-a-client-id-is-it-at-all-possible)).

To answer your question though, no. As Soundcloud says when you attempt to register an app, "...we will no longer be processing API application requests at this time."

I'm trying to use the API too. It seems like we either need to use client IDs belonging to other people, wait an unspecified period of time, or there may be select uses of their API that don't require a client ID.